# Windows Azure ACS: Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel"

Tags: azure, acs

I have ASP webrole that works great without ACS. When i add ACS to the my application it works fine locally. However when i deploy it to the cloud its doesnt seem to be packaging the Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll.

Now I have done the following:

1. Ensured under the References that copy local = true for "Microsoft.IdentityModel"
2. Tired re-adding the STS references.
   3.Right click>>Add referance>>Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll

This used to also work fine without having to install WIF on the actual server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi MAC can u tell me where u add your dll reference.In which project solution?I face that problem Before i use my dll reference in console application and face the same issue.

Comment: Im adding the reference to the WebRole solution which is a Web Applciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to find what was causing the issue. So I had 1 x WebRole and also 1 X WCF role in the same solution. ACS worked fine up until three steps later in the application once I tried to use the WCF service. At point it stuck me that the Azure creates a VM per role. So this made total since why it authenticated fine up to the point when I tried to use the WCF service.  The assembly was not missing from the WebRole but rather from the WCF VM that it created. So I made sure that WIF was also installed on that VM and bang it worked. I still don’t understand 100% why I would have to have to install WIF on the WCF VM but in the end that what was causing my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out these resources, which might help you solving your issue:

- [Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697596/azure-service-configuration-error)
- MSDN Documentation: [Unable to Find Assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel' When RoleEnvironmentAPIs are Called](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh403974.aspx)
- [ACS Walkthrough from Windows Azure Team (new)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2011/12/12/brand-new-acs-walkthrough-on-the-new-windows-azure-developer-center.aspx)
- [Powershell script on GitHub for Installing WIF via Stratup Task](https://gist.github.com/1037384)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok so its a known issue, thanks for the links. But i still haven't been able to resolve this issue. This [link](http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2011/11/executing-powershell-script-with.html) was a bit more helpful but in that case the VM kept cycling and eventually stopped. My next step was to deploy>>>RDP to the VM>> and manually run the power shell scipt. This did install WIF on the VM however i still got the error:Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel". arg arg arg.....

Comment: How come provided links did not help. I used the GIT PowerShell Scrtipt for installing WIF and it works. What issues do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is described in this [post](http://blogs.infosupport.com/adding-assemblies-to-the-gac-in-windows-azure/) under "using windows update packages section" (but I had to make some minor changes to the startup script)

Basically, I had to create a Startup Task, which executes batch file InstallWif.cmd that I've created under my web project. I also downloaded and included WIF install package (Windows6.0-KB974405-x64.msu) into my web project. I set "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy Always" for **both** of these files.

InstallWif.cmd contained the following script

```
@echo off
sc config wuauserv start= demand
wusa.exe "%~dp0Windows6.0-KB974405-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart
sc config wuauserv start= disabled
exit /b 0
```

Note that I had to use Windows6.0-KB974405-x64.msu and not Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu. I found out that 6.1 version wouldn't install by logging to Azure VM instance using a remote desktop connection to Azure and trying to manually install this version there.

Startup task is defined inside ServiceDefinition.csdef file like this

```
 <Startup>
   <Task commandLine="InstallWif.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
 </Startup>
```